# Vue: Set child-component data with props values not working

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Simply, I have two components:

- **Parent component** which passes a prop object called "profile"
- **Child component** which receives the profile prop

The profile value is an object like this:

```
{
  name: "Something",
  email: "some@thing.com"
}
```

**What happens?**

The child component receives perfectly the profile value in the template, but it seems impossible to retrieve and set it to the component data.

**What is the goal?**

I want to initialise the value "email" with the profile email prop.

**What did I expect?**

```
export default {
  props: ["profile"],
  data() {
    return {
      email: this.profile.email
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I haven't specified that email is a data value used as model.
I have just tried to remove it and simply print the value of email in the template and it doesn't work as well.

```js
<!-- PARENT COMPONENT -->

<template>
  <dialog-settings ref="dialogSettings" :profile="profile"></dialog-settings>
</template>

<script>

import Auth from "../services/apis/auth";
import DialogSettings from "../components/dialog-settings";

export default {
 name: "app",
  components: {
    "dialog-settings": DialogSettings
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    Auth.checkToken()
      .then(profile => {
        this.profile = profile;
      })
      .catch(err => {
      });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: "App",
      drawer: true,
      profile: {},
      navItems: []
    };
  }
}
</script>

<!-- CHILD COMPONENT -->

<template>
  {{profile}} <!-- All the fields are passed and available (e.g. profile.email)-->
  {{email}} <!-- Email is not defined -->
</template>

<script>

import Auth from "../services/apis/auth";
import DialogSettings from "../components/dialog-settings";

export default {
 name: "dialog-settings",
  props: ["profile"],
  data() {
    return {
      email: this.profile.email
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have tried several things and I think that the problem is the asynchronous call to the API in the beforeCreate().

Comment: This has to work. i don't see any bugs in your code. Post your full code of parent and child component.

Answer (score 1):

your child component email property should be a computed value

```
<!-- CHILD COMPONENT -->

<template>
  <div>
    {{profile}} <!-- All the fields are passed and available (e.g. profile.email)-->
    {{email}} <!-- Email is not defined -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Auth from "../services/apis/auth";
import DialogSettings from "../components/dialog-settings";

export default {
    name: "dialog-settings",
  props: ["profile"],
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  computed: {
    email () {
      return this.profile ? this.profile.email : 'no email yet'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

That's because parent component property is set after rendering child component.
"Data" is not reactive, it's set once when component is created. Prop 'profile" is reactive so first when you render component you should see {} and after response from Auth is set.
If you still want to keep it in data, you could display child component like that:

```
<dialog-settings ref="dialogSettings" :profile="profile" v-if="profile.email"></dialog-settings>
```

But i wouldn't recommend that!

Comment: What is your best practice in this situation since you don't recommend it?

Comment: I would recommend you to use this computed property solution from top of my post. I do not recommend only this thing with v-if.